# MySQL Date Between Subquery Question

Tags: mysql, date, subquery

Ok, I have a subquery that I am trying to work with and was needing a complicated question answered. There is a SQL tool that is being used to generate reports. With this tool, you can select dates as long as the date is in the outer select statement. So, you can use this tool to select a date range for instance from a simple select statement like this:

```
select date_entered, name from opportunities
```

This will work fine with the tool.

However, I have a SQL requirement where I need to have each column be it's own SQL statement (basically, a series of subqueries). My question is - is there anyway to have a subquery use the date from the initial select? Here is a sample of a select statement that I am having to do:

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT
        count(
            opportunities.id) AS "count_for_opp_id"

    FROM
        opportunities 
LEFT JOIN opportunities_cstm ON opportunities.id = opportunities_cstm.id_c
WHERE
    opportunities.deleted = '0'
AND ((curdate() - interval 0 day) <= opportunities.date_entered)
AND opportunities_cstm.lead_category_c = 'GM Internet'
AND opportunities_cstm.lead_type_c = 'Sales'
AND opportunities_cstm.partner_id_c LIKE '41%'
OR opportunities_cstm.partner_id_c LIKE '42%'
OR opportunities_cstm.partner_id_c LIKE '43%'
OR opportunities_cstm.partner_id_c LIKE '44%'
OR opportunities_cstm.partner_id_c LIKE '45%'
OR opportunities_cstm.partner_id_c LIKE '47%'
OR opportunities_cstm.partner_id_c LIKE '48%'
OR opportunities_cstm.partner_id_c LIKE '49%'
OR opportunities_cstm.lead_sub_type_c = 'GM 3rd Party'
)AS TOT_DIV_THIRD_PARTY_SALES_LEADS,
(
SELECT
count(opportunities.id) AS "count_for_opp_id"
FROM
opportunities left
    JOIN opportunities_cstm ON opportunities.id = opportunities_cstm.id_c
WHERE
    opportunities.deleted = '0'
AND ((curdate() - interval 0 day) <= opportunities.date_entered)
AND opportunities_cstm.lead_category_c = 'Dealer Web'
AND opportunities_cstm.lead_type_c = 'Sales'
AND opportunities_cstm.lead_sub_type_c = 'GM Dealer Website'
OR opportunities_cstm.lead_sub_type_c = 'DMA Landing Page'
)AS TOT_DEALER_WEBSITE_DMA_SALES_LEADS,
(
    SELECT
        count(opportunities.id) AS "count_for_opp_id"
    FROM
        opportunities left
    JOIN opportunities_cstm ON opportunities.id = opportunities_cstm.id_c
JOIN leads_handling_objectives
WHERE
opportunities.deleted = '0'
AND ((curdate() - interval 0 day) <= opportunities.date_entered)
AND opportunities_cstm.lead_category_c = 'GM Internet'
AND opportunities_cstm.partner_id_c LIKE '41%'
OR opportunities_cstm.partner_id_c LIKE '42%'
OR opportunities_cstm.partner_id_c LIKE '43%'
OR opportunities_cstm.partner_id_c LIKE '44%'
OR opportunities_cstm.partner_id_c LIKE '45%'
OR opportunities_cstm.partner_id_c LIKE '47%'
OR opportunities_cstm.partner_id_c LIKE '48%'
OR opportunities_cstm.partner_id_c LIKE '49%'
OR opportunities_cstm.lead_sub_type_c = 'GM 3rd Party'
AND opportunities_cstm.time_followup_c <= leads_handling_objectives.resp_time_obj
AND opportunities_cstm.make_c = leads_handling_objectives.makes_carried
AND opportunities_cstm.time_followup_c IS NOT NULL
)AS NUM_OF_LEADS_RESP_ONTIME_DIVISIONAL_THIRD_PARTY,
(
    SELECT
        count(opportunities.id) AS "count_for_opp_id"
    FROM
        opportunities left
    JOIN opportunities_cstm ON opportunities.id = opportunities_cstm.id_c
JOIN leads_handling_objectives
WHERE
opportunities.deleted = '0'
AND ((curdate() - interval 0 day) <= opportunities.date_entered)
AND opportunities_cstm.lead_category_c = 'Dealer Web'
AND opportunities_cstm.lead_sub_type_c = 'GM Dealer Website'
OR opportunities_cstm.lead_sub_type_c = 'DMA Landing Page'
AND opportunities_cstm.time_followup_c <= leads_handling_objectives.resp_time_obj
AND opportunities_cstm.make_c = leads_handling_objectives.makes_carried
AND opportunities_cstm.time_followup_c IS NOT NULL
)AS NUM_OF_LEADS_RESP_ONTIME_DEALERWEBSITE_DMA
```

If you look at this query, you will notice the curdate...<= date_entered part of the subquery. I need to really have this on the outer layer somehow of the select statement. However, if I put this on the outer layer, I am not sure how to make the subquery use the date range that way.

I know this is a complicated question but - would there be any advice at all from anyone out there? Thanks!

(note: Also, this cannot be a procedure or a function. It has to be a select statement or a view to work with the reporting tool.)

One more edit - an easier (smaller) snippet of the SQL above can be focused on here:

```
SELECT
(SELECT
        count(
            opportunities.id) AS "count_for_opp_id"

    FROM
        opportunities 
LEFT JOIN opportunities_cstm ON opportunities.id = opportunities_cstm.id_c
WHERE
    opportunities.deleted = '0'
AND ((curdate() - interval 0 day) <= opportunities.date_entered)
AND opportunities_cstm.lead_category_c = 'GM Internet'
AND opportunities_cstm.lead_type_c = 'Sales'
) AS TOT_DIV_THIRD_PARTY_SALES_LEADS
```

This one above might be easier to read and easier to diagnose in the long run.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have all those _utf8's all over the place? Isn't it easier to correctly set the collation settings?

Comment: There's no way I'm going to correct all of this, but **please** learn when to use brackets.  This is overly verbose, which won't make getting help easy.  And it's a nightmare to maintain - an incorrectly matched bracket will not give you a syntax error.

Comment: Sorry guys. This is something I inherited. Not necessarily something I wanted to create myself. :)

That's why I posted that it would be a complicated question. However, not much I can do about that right now at this moment. Will have to tackle that later on. Does anyone have any comments related to the question posted?

Thanks!

Comment: Just edited the SQL statement really quick. I took out all of the superfluous parenthesis and _utf8's. Hopefully, this will make this a little more readable (even for me!  :)

Thanks!

Comment: @NullUserException - this sort of thing is quite normal and natural. I'd suggest to the swhitlow (and anyone planning to try this at home) that it is permitted to embed comments in SQL statements; I find this useful when they grow to this size or larger. (Apologies if you edited them out.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your (smaller) query as it stands lacks a FROM. Putting one in will give you a hook to hang the curdate() function from...

```
SELECT (SELECT count(opportunities.id) AS "count_for_opp_id"
            FROM opportunities LEFT JOIN opportunities_cstm ON opportunities.id = opportunities_cstm.id_c
            WHERE opportunities.deleted              = '0' AND
                  ((curdate() - interval 0 day)     <= opportunities.date_entered) AND 
                  opportunities_cstm.lead_category_c = 'GM Internet' AND
                  opportunities_cstm.lead_type_c     = 'Sales') AS TOT_DIV_THIRD_PARTY_SALES_LEADS
    FROM any_table
    LIMIT 1;
```

Second suggestion...

```
SELECT <given date>,
       (SELECT count(opportunities.id) AS "count_for_opp_id"
            FROM opportunities LEFT JOIN opportunities_cstm ON opportunities.id = opportunities_cstm.id_c
            WHERE opportunities.deleted              = '0' AND
                  (<given date>                     <= opportunities.date_entered AND 
                  opportunities_cstm.lead_category_c = 'GM Internet' AND
                  opportunities_cstm.lead_type_c     = 'Sales') AS TOT_DIV_THIRD_PARTY_SALES_LEADS
    FROM any_table
    LIMIT 1;
```

The given date can be a literal or a variable or it could be present in the any_table; it will work its way into the subquery just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately, this would not work for the curdate since the subquery would still be limited to the curdate inside the subquery. 

I am basically needing something like this:
select <date_entered_variable>, (select count...from opportunities where opportunities.date_entered <= <date_entered_variable>) as total_count
from opportunities

Comment: I've made a second suggestion, but I'm still not quite sure what the difficulty is. The date doesn't need to be selected inside the subquery to be available to it.